# Date function output in a local language

Tags: php, date

I am trying to output dates in the Italian format using `date()` as follows:

```
<?php 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');
    echo date("D d M Y", $row['eventtime']); 
?>
```

However, it is still coming out in the English format. What else could I do? Is there something wrong?

The solution has to be script specific and not server-wide.

Comment: http://www.phpnews.it/articoli/ottenere-date-in-italiano/

Comment: I used your solution here: inmaremma.net Just that the accent characters are rendered as question marks. I believe I correctly set html language to italian with <html lang="it-IT">

Comment: @AdiCumpanasu You'll likely also need to set the charset to UTF-8. Place the following between `<head>` and `</head>`: `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Comment: solved it wrapping like this: utf8_encode( strftime("%A %d %B %Y") )

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[`date()`](http://php.net/date) is not locale-aware. You should use [`strftime()`](http://php.net/strftime) and its format specifiers to output locale-aware dates (from the [`date()`](http://php.net/date) PHP manual):

> To format dates in other languages,
>   you should use the [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/setlocale) and
>   [`strftime()`](http://php.net/strftime) functions instead of
>   [`date()`](http://php.net/date).

Regarding [Anti Veeranna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135594/anti-veeranna)'s comment: he is absolutely right, since you have to be very careful with setting locales as they are sometimes not limited to the current script scope. The best way would be:

```php
$oldLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT');
echo utf8_encode( strftime("%a %d %b %Y", $row['eventtime']) );
setlocale(LC_TIME, $oldLocale);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that setlocale is not script specific, it is thread specific, so it is possible that the locale changes 'underneath' you.

http://ee.php.net/setlocale explains it too.

Comment: It is not even just thread specific, it's process specific. So you might change other running PHP instances, too. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#refsect1-function.setlocale-notes)

Comment: `strftime` is deprecates since PHP 8.1. See here for an updated answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73250691/1671294

Answer (score 15):

I found that `setlocale` isn't reliable, as it is set per process, not per thread (the manual mentions this). This means other running scripts can change the locale at any time. A solution is using [IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) from the `intl` php extension.

```php
$fmt = new \IntlDateFormatter('it_IT', NULL, NULL);
$fmt->setPattern('d MMMM yyyy HH:mm'); 
// See: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime for pattern syntax
echo $fmt->format(new \DateTime());
```

If it doesn't work you might need to:

- Install `intl` php extension (ubuntu example): `sudo apt-get install php5-intl`
- Install the locale you want to use: `sudo locale-gen it_IT`

Comment: This solution is more reliable than the accepted answer (having `intl` php extension installed and the appropriate locale available)

Comment: Since strftime is depreciated in php8.0, IntlDateFormatter  is a great solution! 
It can also be written shorter like this (including the timezone (if required) and pattern in the object call):       
$fmt = new \IntlDateFormatter('it_IT', NULL, NULL, 'Europe/Rome', NULL, 'd MMMM yyyy HH:mm');

Comment: The given install command is misleading. It should be made clear that one need to install the same version that the browser's PHP extension uses (e.g. for PHP 7.4 use "php7.4-intl" for the name, or the latest (use "php-intl")!

Answer (score 4):

it_IT locale has to be installed/enabled by your server admin, otherwise this will not work.

So, Jonathan's solution is probably the best.

Comment: I have full access to the server, any ideas where i can check which local are installed?

Comment: by typing 'locale -a' if that server is running some variant of Linux/BSD.

Comment: To check and install a locale on the server: https://askubuntu.com/a/76106

Answer (score 0):

About the article on [http://www.phpnews.it/articoli/ottenere-date-in-italiano/response](http://www.phpnews.it/articoli/ottenere-date-in-italiano/), the blog suggest an alternative method, but the code is not working, here is the correct code:

```
function timestamp_to_date_italian($date)
    {       
        $months = array(
                '01' => 'Gennaio', 
                '02' => 'Febbraio', 
                '03' => 'Marzo', 
                '04' => 'Aprile',
                '05' => 'Maggio', 
                '06' => 'Giugno', 
                '07' => 'Luglio', 
                '08' => 'Agosto',
                '09' => 'Settembre', 
                '10' => 'Ottobre', 
                '11' => 'Novembre',
                '12' => 'Dicembre');

        list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-',date('d-m-Y', $date));      
        return $day . ' ' . $months[$month] . ' ' . $year;

    }
```