# Formatting DateTime object, respecting Locale::getDefault()

Tags: php, datetime-format

I have a DateTime object which I'm currently formating via

```
$mytime->format("D d.m.Y")
```

Which gives me exactly the format I need:

> Tue 5.3.2012

The only missing point is the correct language. I need German translation of `Tue` (`Tuesday`), which is `Die` (`Dienstag`).

This gives me the right locale setting

```
Locale::getDefault()
```

But I don't know how to tell `DateTime::format` to use it.

Isn't there a way to do something like:

```
$mytime->format("D d.m.Y", \Locale::getDefault());
```

Comment: take care: strftime("%a %e.%l.%Y", \Locale::getDefault()) does not work (at least here on my setup), since getDefault() returns "de" instead of "de_DE"...

Comment: The second parameter of strftime should be the timestamp, not a locale.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Completely clear that this does not work. What I actually wanted to tell is that setlocale(LC_TIME, \Locale::getDefault()) does not work (in my symfony2 app)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

That's because `format` does not pay attention to locale. You should use [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) instead.

For example:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE"); //only necessary if the locale isn't already set
$formatted_time = strftime("%a %e.%l.%Y", $mytime->getTimestamp())
```

Comment: This behavior is noted in the php docs on [DateTime::format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php): *`This method does not use locales. All output is in English.`*

Comment: strftime() doesn't work with dates before 1970, Date_time::format() doesn't work with locales... is there anything that works with both?

Comment: @Jay K: It's always possible to extend PHP's native DateTime Class to add localization to it.

Comment: Actually, we found that strftime() does work with pre-1970 dates if you pass it a (negative) unix timestamp (on our server, at least)... so we do this combination of the two:


    `$datetime = new DateTime('1920-01-01');
    setLocale(LC_TIME|LC_CTYPE, $locale_based_on_user_profile);
    return strftime($format, $datetime->format('U'));`

Comment: @Jonathan format modifier should be **%m** instead of %l to display month number

Comment: If your lang code doesn't work, then try passing proper names to `setlocale()`, like: `French`, `German` or `Polish`.

Comment: The strftime() function is deprecated in PHP 8.1, and will be removed in PHP 9. See the top-voted answer about DateTIme with the Intl extension.

Comment: strftime is now deprecated as of PHP 8.0.1

Answer (score 157):

You can use the [Intl](http://php.net/intl) extension to format the date. It will format dates/times according to the chosen locale, or you can override that with [`IntlDateFormatter::setPattern()`](http://php.net/intldateformatter.setpattern).

A quicky example of using a custom pattern, for your desired output format, might look like.

```
$dt = new DateTime;

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('de_DE', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
$formatter->setPattern('E d.M.yyyy');

echo $formatter->format($dt);
```

Which outputs the following (for today, at least).

> Di. 4.6.2013

Comment: it's good that you answered an ancient question, because this question pops up at the top of google search results and used to only provide outdated information.

Comment: Plus you get the "Necromancer" badge when you (successfully) reply to an old question.

Comment: You can easily install the extension as follows: `yum install php-intl` `apachectl reload`

Comment: For those who want to change the output format check: http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details

Comment: You're a lifesaver.  I was getting worried because the documentation for setlocale() suggests it's not thread-safe.

Comment: You should know that PHPs IntlDateFormatter class uses ISO date format codes instead of PHPs date() format codes. I
A good list to find ISO codes is available at http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.constants.html#zend.date.constants.selfdefinedformats

Answer (score 15):

[IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/de/intldateformatter.create.php) is the way to go currently (2023).

```php
<?php
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    $locale,  // the locale to use, e.g. 'en_GB'
    $dateFormat,  // how the date should be formatted, e.g. IntlDateFormatter::FULL
    $timeFormat,  // how the time should be formatted, e.g. IntlDateFormatter::FULL 
    'Europe/Berlin'  // the time should be returned in which timezone?
);

echo $formatter->format(time());
```

Will give a different output, depending on what you pass as `$locale` and the date and time format. I wanted to add some samples for future reference. Note that `IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN` and `IntlDateFormatter::LONG` are interchangable.

```
Locale: en_US
Format for Date & Time:           Results in:
IntlDateFormatter::FULL           Friday, August 5, 2022 at 3:26:37 PM Central European Summer Time 
IntlDateFormatter::LONG           August 5, 2022 at 3:26:37 PM GMT+2 
IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM         Aug 5, 2022, 3:26:37 PM 
IntlDateFormatter::SHORT          8/5/22, 3:26 PM 



Locale: en_GB
Format for Date & Time:           Results in:
IntlDateFormatter::FULL           Friday, 5 August 2022 at 15:26:37 Central European Summer Time 
IntlDateFormatter::LONG           5 August 2022 at 15:26:37 CEST 
IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM         5 Aug 2022, 15:26:37 
IntlDateFormatter::SHORT          05/08/2022, 15:26 



Locale: de_DE
Format for Date & Time:           Results in:
IntlDateFormatter::FULL           Freitag, 5. August 2022 um 15:26:37 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit 
IntlDateFormatter::LONG           5. August 2022 um 15:26:37 MESZ 
IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM         05.08.2022, 15:26:37 
IntlDateFormatter::SHORT          05.08.22, 15:26 



Locale: fr_FR
Format for Date & Time:           Results in:
IntlDateFormatter::FULL           vendredi 5 août 2022 à 15:26:37 heure d’été d’Europe centrale 
IntlDateFormatter::LONG           5 août 2022 à 15:26:37 UTC+2 
IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM         5 août 2022 à 15:26:37 
IntlDateFormatter::SHORT          05/08/2022 15:26
```

As salathe has already said, you can also use [`$formatter->setPattern`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/intldateformatter.setpattern.php) to further customize the output if needed.

Answer (score 2):

While `setlocale()` is the correct answer and will still work but is outdated now.

> [strftime](https://www.php.net/strftime) has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.1.0 Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

And mentioned [Intl](https://www.php.net/intl) extension works perfectly, but not always handy.

One of the simplest ways to work with dates and times is to use [Carbon2](https://carbon.nesbot.com/), [CakePHP Chronos](https://github.com/cakephp/chronos) or similar library. It provides a single interface to all date's manipulations, formatting, and calculations. If you work with dates a lot I recommend using Carbon and then doing something like this

```
$date = Carbon::now()->locale('fr_FR');
echo $date->isoFormat('dd DD.MM.YYYY');
```

Please note that the format differs from the `date()` one. Full list see [in Carbon docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization) but mentioned `D d.m.Y` can be something like `dd DD.MM.YYYY`.

If your project accepts 3rd party libraries, it's really the way to go. Also, if you're using the framework, please check, maybe Carbon (or its wrapper) is already included.

Answer (score 1):

I made something that just does that, because there doesn't seem to exist a simple solution anywhere online, except for with `strftime`, which is very much deprecated!

My solution extends `DateTime::format()` with international month and day names and doesn't require installing a bunch of modules, learning new date formatting ways, etc.

After including the classes provided below you can use it as follows. Instead of

```
$date = new DateTime("2010-01-01 1:23");
echo $date->format("l (D) Y-M-d (F)");
```

Result: `Friday (Fri) 2010-Jan-01 (January)`

You can now use

```
$date = new DateTimeIntl("2010-01-01 1:23");
echo $date->format("l (D) Y-M-d (F)");
```

Result: `vrijdag (vr) 2010-jan.-01 (januari)` (Dutch locale).

You can dynamically change the `$datetime->locale` if wanted.

```
$date = new DateTimeIntl("2010-01-01 1:23");
$date->locale = "it_IT" ;
echo $date->format("l (D) Y-M-d (F)");
```

Result: `venerdì (ven) 2010-gen-01 (gennaio)`

Include this:

```
class DateTimePatternReplace {
    function __construct(public string $DateTimeCode, 
                         public string $IntDateFormatterCode,
                         public string $tempDateTimePlaceHolder) {}
}

trait addIntlDate {

    public string $locale="nl_NL" ;  // REPLACE BY YOUR FAVORITE LOCALE

    private function getIntResult(string $pattern) {
        if ( ! isset($this->formatter) || $this->formatter->getLocale(Locale::VALID_LOCALE) != $this->locale ) { 
            $this->formatter = new IntlDateFormatter($this->locale);
            $this->locale = $this->formatter->getLocale(Locale::VALID_LOCALE); // store the valid version of the locale
        }
        this->formatter->setPattern($pattern);
        return $this->formatter->format($this);
    }

    function format(string $pattern): string {
        // The third parameter can NOT contain normal latin letters, these are random, 
        // distinctive codes not likely to be in a date format string
        $replacePatterns = [/*weekdays*/new DateTimePatternReplace('l', 'EEEE', '[*ł*]'), 
                                        new DateTimePatternReplace('D', 'EEE', '[*Đ*]'),
                            /*month*/   new DateTimePatternReplace('F', 'MMMM', '[*ƒ*]'), 
                                        new DateTimePatternReplace('M', 'MMM', '[*μ*]'),
                                        // add new replacements here if needed
                           ] ;
        $codesFound=[] ;
        foreach($replacePatterns as $p) {
            if ( str_contains($pattern, $p->DateTimeCode)) {
                // replace codes not prepended by a backslash.
                // known bug: codes prepended by double backslashes will not be translated. Whatever.
                $pattern = preg_replace('/(?<!\\\)'.preg_quote($p->DateTimeCode)."/", $p->tempDateTimePlaceHolder, $pattern);
                $codesFound[] = $p ;
            }
        }
        $result = parent::format($pattern) ;
        foreach($codesFound as $p) {
            $code = $this->getIntResult($p->IntDateFormatterCode);
            $result = str_replace($p->tempDateTimePlaceHolder, $code, $result);
        }
        return $result ;
    }
} 

// you can remove this str_contains addition in PHP 8 or higher
if (!function_exists('str_contains')) {
    function str_contains($haystack, $needle) {
        return $needle !== '' && mb_strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false;
    }
}
// end str_contains addition


class DateTimeIntl extends DateTime {
    use addIntlDate;
}

class DateTimeImmutableIntl extends DateTimeImmutable {
    use addIntlDate;  
}
```

This code extends DateTime and DateTimeImmutable, extends their normal formatting with a locale. So this keeps everything extremely simple

You can add new patterns to be translated if needed by adding codes to the array: a formatting pattern in `DateTime::format()`-syntax, a corresponding formatting pattern in `IntlDateFormatter::format`-syntax, plus a placeholder to be used in `DateTime::format` that does NOT contains letters/codes/patterns that will be used/replaced by the `DateTime::format` method. See as example the current four codes that use no letters in ASCII lower than 128 letters. (They do use Polish, Greek, Dutch and Slovak letters just for fun.)

**Built and tested in PHP 8.1.**
For some **older version of PHP** you will have to change the first class to

```
class DateTimePatternReplace {
    public string $DateTimeCode;
    public string $IntDateFormatterCode;
    public string $tempDateTimePlaceHolder;

    function __construct(string $DateTimeCode, string $IntDateFormatterCode, string $tempDateTimePlaceHolder) {
         $this->DateTimeCode = $DateTimeCode;
         $this->IntDateFormatterCode = $IntDateFormatterCode;
         $this->tempDateTimePlaceHolder = $tempDateTimePlaceHolder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how I solved combining the features of **DateTime** and **strftime()**.

The first allows us to manage strings with a weird date format, for example "Ymd" (stored in db from a datepicker).
The second allows us to translate a date string in some language.

For example we start from a value "20201129", and we want end with an italian readable date, with the name of day and month, also the first letter uppercase: "Domenica 29 novembre 2020".

```
// for example we start from a variable like this
$yyyymmdd = '20201129';

// set the local time to italian
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT.utf8');

// convert the variable $yyyymmdd to a real date with DateTime
$truedate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $yyyymmdd);

// check if the result is a date (true) else do nothing
if($truedate){

  // output the date using strftime
  // note the value passed using format->('U'), it is a conversion to timestamp
  echo ucfirst(strftime('%A %d %B %Y', $truedate->format('U')));

}

// final result: Domenica 29 novembre 2020
```