# PHP: date "F" with setlocale not working

Tags: php, date, setlocale

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $event_date = get_sub_field('event_date'); // 20150203
    $event_date_format = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $event_date);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');
    ?>  
    <li>
        <h6><?php echo $event_date_format->format('d');?>. <?php echo $event_date_format->format('F');?></h6>
        <p><?php echo $event_date_format->format('H');?>:<?php echo $event_date_format->format('i');?></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The output of this is

```
03. February 
19:25
```

Why does setlocale not have any impact on this. I want my Month "F" to be in german like `3. Feber 19:25`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

If I try using `strftime()` i suddenly get a different date output. it is in german but wrong?

```
<ul>
        <?php
        $event_date = get_sub_field('event_date');
        $event_date_format = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $event_date);
        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');
        ?>  
        <li>
            <h6><?php echo $event_date_format->format('d');?>. <?php echo strftime('%B', $event_date);?></h6>
            <p><?php echo $event_date_format->format('H');?>:<?php echo $event_date_format->format('i');?></p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Suddenly the output date is not `03. February` but `03. August`, even though the date should be February.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE 2:**

This is pretty weird. I just checked the variable `$event_date` online in a unix conversion tool and the I get this …

> $event_date: 20150203

`Sat, 22 Aug 1970 05:16:43 GMT`

The value is set inside a wordpress backend with a datepicker and clearly says 03/02/2015

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTime::format and strftime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906937/datetimeformat-and-strftime)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567450/php-setlocale-doesnt-work/45848706#45848706

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`date()` and DateTime do not respect locale

use `strftime()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and
>   strftime() functions instead of date().

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question with the changed `<?php echo strftime('%B', $event_date);?>`. However I have the problem now, that my month is different for some reason? It should be "Feber" (february) and not "August" as it is output now.

Comment: You began to use $event_date_format, but for this call you are still using $event_date, which is the string '20150302'.  the strftime is treating that as an integer, in epoch time (aka Unix Timestamp, number of seconds since Jan 1 1970).  You should instead use ``strftime('%B', $event_date_format->getTimestamp() )``

Comment: Deprecated function in PHP 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

Annoyingly, `date` is not locale-aware.  From the manual:

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and
>   strftime() functions instead of date.

You probably want:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');
echo strftime('%B');
```

Alternatively, checkout [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization).  It's got a consistent API that includes locale-awareness.  As an example:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'German');
echo Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%B'); // Sonntag
```

Comment: Deprecated function in PHP 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME,'de_DE.UTF8');
$eventDate = new DateTime(get_field('event_date'));
$eventDate_ts = $eventDate->getTimestamp();
echo gmstrftime("%B", $eventDate_ts);
```

Character coding is set to ['de_DE.UTF8'](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php#98329) for German, [gmstrftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmstrftime.php#51171) is used here, [also](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php#refsect1-function.strftime-parameters).

> March to März, Mar to Mrz.

The Member function of DateTime() generates the necessary Timestamp.

Comment: Deprecated function in PHP 8.1.