# Best way to translate datetime DAY to other languages

Tags: php

I translate the days "Mon -Fri" to my native language. For this you can choose difrent ways. There is `if` `case` `array` etc.. I now wounder if there is something wrong doing it the way i did choose. (`if`) ?

**PHP**

```
//Translate days to Swedish
if($day == "Mon"){
  $day = "Mån";
}
if($day == "Tue"){
  $day = "Tis";
}
if($day == "Wed"){
  $day = "Ons";
}
if($day == "Thu"){
  $day = "Tor";
}
if($day == "Fri"){
  $day = "Fre";
}
if($day == "Sat"){
  $day = "Lör";
}
if($day == "Sun"){
  $day = "Sön";
}
```

Comment: You can use `IF` `ELSEIF`.

Comment: Please look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744952/php-how-to-format-a-given-datetime-object-considering-localegetdefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is ok. However you are comparing 7 times the `$day` variable regardless if it was matched previously.

A refactoring of your code would be as follows:

```
if($day == "Mon"){
  $day = "Mån";
}elseif($day == "Tue"){
  $day = "Tis";
}elseif($day == "Wed"){
  $day = "Ons";
}elseif($day == "Thu"){
  $day = "Tor";
}elseif($day == "Fri"){
  $day = "Fre";
}elseif($day == "Sat"){
  $day = "Lör";
}else{
  $day = "Sön";
}
```

This way if the `$day` was matched it avoids executing the other comparison.

Alternately you can use switch case this will avoid you typing repetitive codes:

```
$day = "Tue";

switch($day){
    case "Mon":
        $day = "Mån";
        break;
    case "Tue":
        $day = "Tis";
        break;
    case "Wed":
        $day = "Ons";
        break;
    case "Thu":
        $day = "Tor";
        break;
    case "Fri":
        $day = "Fre";
        break;
    case "Sat":
        $day = "Lör";
        break;
    case "Sun":
        $day = "Sön";
        break;
}
echo $day;
```

The best way is to use an array this avoid you performing conditional statements (if elseif and case)

```
$days = array(
    "Mon" => "Mån",
    "Tue" => "Tis",
    "Wed" => "Ons",
    "Thu" => "Tor",
    "Fri" => "Fre",
    "Sat" => "Lör",
    "Sun" => "Sön"
    );

echo $days["Fri"];
```

Comment: Seriously? Accepted answer? And what if you have to translate your dates to 10 different languages?

Comment: Read the question first. The user didn't asked neither for multi-language translation nor dates. He asked only for his native language translation and asked about the effectiveness of his approach.

Comment: Ok ok, you are absolutly right. But at least add several variants to your answer. And `switch` will be more compact.

Comment: Agree with you. Added variants.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array.

```
    $myDays = array("Mon"=>"Mån","Tue"=>"Tis","Wed"=>"Ons","Thu"=>"Tor","Fri"=>"Fre","Sat"=>"Lör","Sun"=>"Sön");

echo $myDays[date("D", strtotime('now'))];
```