# How can I change the date format of a german date?

Tags: php

I want to convert my date into another format, but it is not working, because my date is in German:

```
$input = 'Dez 21, 2015 23:11';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M j, Y H:i', $input);
$output = $date->format('Y-m-j,');
```

Is there a way to create another format also from a german date? Because I cannot change the local of my page.

---

With the help of your suggestions, I created this code:

```
$fmt = datefmt_create("en_EN", IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 'Europe/London', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);
$output = datefmt_format($fmt , time());
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M j, Y H:i', $input);
$output = $date->format('Y-m-j');
```

But there must be still a mistake.

This is another try, but still no success:

```
$input = 'Dez 21, 2015 23:11';
$dt = $input;
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('en_EN', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
$formatter->setPattern('Y-m-j';
$output = $formatter->format($dt);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.settimezone.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting DateTime object, respecting Locale::getDefault()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744952/formatting-datetime-object-respecting-localegetdefault)

Comment: I`ll check in 5 min because I have to install wamp on my new laptop

Comment: CMS... I see ... you could replace months from GE to EN using str_replace... and then use it however you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want an German date input in the format you provided. You need to use the `parse()` method along with the proper [ICU datetime formatting pattern](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax) (it is somewhat different from the patterns used for PHP `DateTime` object).

```php
$input = 'Dez 21, 2015 23:11';
$inputTz = 'Europe/Berlin';
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'de_DE',
    IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
    IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
    $inputTz
);
$formatter->setPattern('MMM d, Y HH:mm');
$output = new DateTime('@' . $formatter->parse($input), new DateTimezone($inputTz));
```

`$output` is now a `DateTime` object and can be manipulated how you wish. You can ingest it, use another `IntlDateFormatter` to format for output, etc.