# How to translate this date format

Tags: php, function, datetime

In a template (Drupal) php.tpl file I have the following:

```
               <?php    
               print date('F j, Y', $comment->created);
               print ' at ' . date('h:ia', $comment->created); 
               ?>
```

But It doesn't print a translation when the site is in a foreign language. How do I make it translate? Using the t() function? If so, how do I rewrite it to include it?

Any and all help is appreciated. :)

**Update:**

Isemi's 2nd solution below works just fine except for the year that prints a Y instead of the year. With a minor adjustment the code becomes:

```
$dateF = t(date('F', $comment->created));
$datej = t(date('j', $comment->created));
$dateY = t(date('Y', $comment->created));
print "{$datej} {$dateF} {$dateY}" . t(' at ') . date('H:i', $comment->created);
```

The "at" is easy to translate as it becomes a separate translatable string. Notice the space before the "a" and after the "t."

Comment: Regarding the language translation, just eliminate the word "at", since the display of a date and time will naturally indicate the moment the comment was made.

Comment: Also, I suggest using javascript to show the date/time, since the client knows its own locale. All the server has to do then is pass the internal time value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `date()` function uses, I believe, the **server**'s locale. You ought to change it in the current process, which may be awkward and could not work in all configurations.

You ought to retrieve the desired locale string, then:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT'); // Depends on the client.

$datel = strftime("%F %j, %Y at %H:%i:%s", $comment->created);
```

but apart from the correct codes (I'm not too sure about %F and %j), you still have the problem of translating 'at', I think.

Alternatively you can get the date piecewise and translate it by parts:

```
$dateF = t(date('F', $comment->created));
$datej = t(date('j', $comment->created));
$dateY = date('Y', $comment->created); // Numeric year not translated.

print "{$dateF} {$datej}, {$dateY} " . t('at')
      . date('h:i', $comment->created);
```

You could also use the Intl extension, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16921843/1428679).

Comment: I used your second option as it works well. I had an issue with the Y (year) though as it would print the "Y" and not the year. So with this minor adjustment, it became: $dateF = t(date('F', $comment->created));
   $datej = t(date('j', $comment->created));
   $dateY = t(date('Y', $comment->created));
   print "{$datej} {$dateF} {$dateY}" . t(' at ') . date('H:i', $comment->created);

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had forgotten to send 'Y' to the date() function. Corrected.