# Get days of the week and their week number in PHP

Tags: php, week-number

I'm a new to PHP and don't know if my request is possible:

I'd need to get an array with the days of the current week and also indicate for each day if it's the first, second, third, fourth or fifth occurrence of that date for the month.

**Examples**

For the 1st week of August 2016, it would be:

```
monday1
tuesday1
wednesday1
thursday1
friday1
saturday1
sunday1
```

But for the last week of August 2016 (which begins in August and ends in September) it would be:

```
monday5
tuesday5
wednesday1
thursday1
friday1
saturday1
sunday1
```

I tried this, but it only works for the current day.

```
$week_of_the_month = ceil(date('d', $time)/7);
$jd = cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
echo jddayofweek($jd,1).$week_of_the_month;
```

Comment: hi, it is important to show us what you have done in code, then we can figure out a solution for you

Comment: What Have You Tried So Far? We Are Not Here To Write A Code From Scratch. Show Us Your Tried Code.

Comment: Yes it is possible but as @MueyiwaMosesIkomi said it's preferred that you show us your work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php can help you get started

Comment: sorry i'm a newbie , i only know how to get for today : 
$week_of_the_month = ceil(date('d', $time)/7);
$jd = cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
echo jddayofweek($jd,1).$week_of_the_month;

Comment: i guess a need a loop for 7days but i've no idea how to do because the day of today can be different of Monday so i can't loop from 1 to 7.

Comment: @pipoulito I have the solution for you but you need to stop editing the question. Leave it as I have done. They have closed your question and won't reopen if it's badly proposed.

Comment: @BadHorsie  ok i stop editing but how can i see your solution ?

Comment: Interesting question. When you say you want to get the days of the current week, do you mean a list of seven days starting from the previous Monday (or Sunday, some countries like the USA consider Sunday as the start of the week), or do you mean the days that land on the 1st, 8th, 15th, 22nd etc. days of the month?

Comment: @DarraghEnright, actually i need to know for each day of the current week, if each day is the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th or 5th of the month. My week start on monday. thanks

Comment: Example, for $d = new DateTime('2016-08-30'), i need : Monday-5, Tuesday-5, Wednesday-5, Thursday-1, Friday-1, Saturday-1, Sunday-1

Comment: Thanks for the update. It looks like @BadHorsie already posted a great answer though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$d = new DateTime();
$days = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $date = $d->format('j');
    $days[$date] = $d->format('l - ') . ceil($date/7);
    $d->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

That will work for the current date, but you can test it on weeks that cross over two months by setting a specific date to work with:

```
$d = new DateTime('2016-08-31');
```

The result is as follows:

```
print_r($days);

Array
(
    [31] => Wednesday - 5
    [1] => Thursday - 1
    [2] => Friday - 1
    [3] => Saturday - 1
    [4] => Sunday - 1
    [5] => Monday - 1
    [6] => Tuesday - 1
)
```

If you want the dates to always start on the Monday of the current week, the `DateTime` constructor allows you to pass in a string as such:

```
$d = new DateTime('monday this week');
```

Today is Thursday, but it gives:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Monday - 1
    [2] => Tuesday - 1
    [3] => Wednesday - 1
    [4] => Thursday - 1
    [5] => Friday - 1
    [6] => Saturday - 1
    [7] => Sunday - 1
)
```

**Changing Language**

If you want to change the language of the date output, that is a separate topic ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744952/formatting-datetime-object-respecting-localegetdefault)). You will need to have the locales/extensions installed on your system. If you don't want to go down that route, you could just map the days into your language yourself:

```
$intlDays = [
    'Monday' => 'Lundi',
    'Tuesday' => 'Mardi',
    'Wednesday' => 'Mercredi',
    'Thursday' => 'Jeudi',
    'Friday' => 'Vendredi',
    'Saturday' => 'Samedi',
    'Sunday' => 'Dimanche'
];

$d = new DateTime('monday this week');
$days = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $date = $d->format('j');
    $output = $d->format('l - ') . ceil($date/7);
    $output = str_replace(array_keys($intlDays), $intlDays, $output);
    $days[$date] = $output;
    $d->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

Comment: I tried with current date 

'$d = new DateTime('2016-08-03');'
an i get :
Array
(
    [4] => Thursday - 1
    [5] => Friday - 1
    [6] => Saturday - 1
    [7] => Sunday - 1
    [8] => Monday - 2
    [9] => Tuesday - 2
    [10] => Wednesday - 2
)

instead of :
Array
(
    [4] =>  Monday - 1
    [5] => Tuesday - 1
    [6] => Wednesday - 1
    [7] => Thrusday - 1
    [8] => Friday - 1
    [9] => Saturday - 1
    [10] => Sunday - 1
)

I alway need from monday to sunday relative to the date current date day
thanks

Comment: actually i need to know for each day of the current week, if each day is the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th or 5th of the month. My week start on monday. thanks

Comment: Example, for $d = new DateTime('2016-08-30'), i need : Monday-5, Tuesday-5, Wednesday-5, Thursday-1, Friday-1, Saturday-1, Sunday-1

Comment: it's OK for $d = new DateTime('2016-08-28'); but not for $d = new DateTime('2016-08-29') for example (i need start on monday)

Comment: i suppose DateInterval should be modified to get days before if current day is not Monday, isn't it ? thanks

Comment: ohh may be simplest is to get the date of the first sate of the week (monday) and send it to new DateTime ?

Comment: @pipoulito Ah, ok, I didn't know you always need Monday first. Yes, you will need to find the start of the week, then pass that to DateTime.

Comment: @pipoulito Please see updated answer, and also use the full updated original code, as I corrected something.

Comment: thanks a lot but i sill have this with monday-2 at [8] instead of monday-1 in[1]
Array ( [2] => Tuesday-1 [3] => Wednesday-1 [4] => Thursday-1 [5] => Friday-1 [6] => Saturday-1 [7] => Sunday-1 [8] => Monday-2 )

Comment: oops sorry it works !!
i did not see you modify the loop too !
Great thanks
(is there any chance to have the days in french ? i tried with set locale but not...)

Comment: Yes but it could be complex if you do not have certain extensions or locales installed on your system. I will not go into that, but see updated answer.