# Convert a DateTime object to a string considering the locale date format

Tags: php, datetime

Is there a way in PHP to get a string from a `DateTime` object considering the date format according to the locale configuration without having an array of `countries => formats` ?

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, '2016-07-27T19:30:00Z');

$ $usadt = /* What PHP function here? */
$ $brazildt = /* What PHP function here? */

echo ("USA Format: " . $usadt);
echo ("Brazil Format: " . $brazildt);

USA Format: 2016/07/27 07:30pm
Brazil Format: 27/07/2016 19:30
```

Comment: the answer you are looking for is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16921843/2162347)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting DateTime object, respecting Locale::getDefault()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744952/formatting-datetime-object-respecting-localegetdefault)

Comment: hum... This is not what I´m looking for, as these posts I need to explicit the format. Year/Month/Day or Day/Month/Year depends on the country, and that sequence I need to come automatically from the locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [strftime() php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) it says

> Format the time and/or date according to locale settings. Month and weekday names and other language-dependent strings respect the current locale set with setlocale().

So take a look at [setlocale()](http://php.net/setlocale) and change it before using formatted date.

**how to format for your datetime locale**

> **%x** [Preferred date representation based on locale, without the time](http://php.net/strftime)
>
> **%X** [Preferred time representation based on locale, without the date](http://php.net/strftime)

**example**

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, '2016-07-27T19:30:00Z');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_US');
$usadt = strftime('%x %X', $dt->getTimestamp());
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR.UTF-8');
$brazildt = strftime('%x %X', $dt->getTimestamp());
echo "USA Format: $usadt<br>";
echo "Brazil Format: $brazildt<br>";
```

**outputs**

`USA Format: 07/27/2016 12:30:00 PM`

`Brazil Format: 27-07-2016 12:30:00`

**note**

I got the locales from [this page](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales);