# DatePeriod not setting the timezone

Tags: php, date, timezone

I am creating a `DatePeriod` and I want to show the names of months and days in French:

```
$timeZoneParis = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris');
$dateDebutCalendrier = new DateTime('2018-11-01', $timeZoneParis);
$dateFinCalendrier = new DateTime('2018-11-31', $timeZoneParis);
$period = new DatePeriod($dateDebutCalendrier,new DateInterval('P1D'),$dateFinCalendrier);
```

Expected result:

> Janvier, Fevrier...

Actual result:

> January, February...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the good time zone"? Can you edit your question to clarify 1. what result you are getting and 2. what result you expect? You're not passing a `DateTimeZone` to `$lastDayThisMonth` - is this intentional, or an omission?

Comment: @DarraghEnright not intentional, i've changed my code to a better format and updated my question :)

Comment: I understand now. This is not something you can configure or control directly using `DateTime` and `DatePeriod` - this is a locale based question, and `DateTime` does not honour locales. You have a few choices, including `IntlDateFormatter` if you have it installed, or `strftime()`. [Here are some helpful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744952/formatting-datetime-object-respecting-localegetdefault)

Comment: I tried this : **echo strftime("%d %B", $dateDebutCalendrier->getTimestamp());** but this is still in English

Comment: @ProjetSin - Check out the dup question, which bears an uncanny resemblance to yours, asked one week earlier.  Are you and that author (kalvn) associated in some way?  This seems like another case of [StackOverflow déjà-vu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191043/why-do-i-get-d%C3%A9j%C3%A0-vu-reading-stackoverflow-questions)...  Can you shed some light on this phenomenon?  Thanks.

Comment: No, I'm absolutly not related to kalvn. It's a big coincidence (I didn't know about the post your talking about)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comment, this is the solution :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR','fra');
echo(strftime("%B", $dateDebutCalendrier->getTimestamp());
```

Small edit : i needed also to add (3*3600) to the time stamp to get the right first  day of the period.