# How to change date string(j F Y) to date(Y-m-d)

Tags: php, date

I have date in string like `7 october 2019` but in polish
`7 sierpnia 2019` and i would like to change it to date (Y-m-d)

I did:

```
$day = '7 sierpnia 2019';
setlocale( LC_TIME, array('pl_PL.UTF-8','pl_PL@euro', 'pl_PL', 'polish'));
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'j F Y', $day);
echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d');
```

but i got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean
```

I need to insert it into DB in format `Y-m-d`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16921843/3859027

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting DateTime object, respecting Locale::getDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744952/formatting-datetime-object-respecting-localegetdefault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is sufficient for your use case, but the code below shows a way to first translate the Polish month names (assumed full name) to English then do the date conversion ([sandbox demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a3bdbb5e24b23da5c62c2ab7257bb622f241a25)):

```php
<?php

$day = '7 sierpnia 2019';
$effective_day = preg_replace_callback('/(\s+)((stycz|lut|mar|kwie|maj|czerw|lip|sierp|wrzes|pazdzier|listopad|grud).*?)(\s+)/i', function ($matches) {
        switch ($matches[3]) {
        case 'stycz':
                return 'January';
        case 'lut':
                return 'February';
        case 'mar':
                return 'March';
        case 'kwie':
                return 'April';
        case 'maj':
                return 'May';
        case 'czerw':
                return 'June';
        case 'lip':
                return 'July';
        case 'sierp':
                return 'August';
        case 'wrzes':
                return 'September';
        case 'pazdzier':
                return 'October';
        case 'listopad':
                return 'November';
        case 'grud':
                return 'December';
        }
        return $matches[0];
}, $day);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j F Y', $effective_day);
echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d');
```

Reference: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~dan/genealogy/Miller/resource/polmonth.htm

Comment: I had to change `preg_replace_callback` string but it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution with [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php). Require the [intl extension installed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php) (i.e. `sudo apt-get install php-intl` for Debian / Ubuntu).

```php
<?php

$day = '7 sierpnia 2019';
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('pl_PL', null, null);
$formatter->setPattern('d M yyyy');
echo (new DateTime('@' . $formatter->parse($day)))->format('Y-m-d');
```