# How to get the month in date changed with according to user timezone in php

Tags: php, datetime, format, timezone, utc

I have tried a datetime as below in php

```
    $datetime           = new \DateTime(''2021-03-23 11:20:15.000000'');
    $datetimeZone       = $datetime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $datetimeZoneFormat = $datetimeZone->format('F, d Y');
```

I am getting an output from this as

**"April, 10 2021"**

But I want the month to be changed according to the user's timezone

**For Example:**

If the user is from France I want the datetime to be **"Avril, 10 2021"**

If the user is from Spain I want the datetime to be **"Abril, 10 2021"**

Can someone please help me on this I am quite new to the technology?

Comment: What you are looking for is not `TimeZone` rather `Locale`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8745094/8607640

Answer (score 0):

It worked. Thanks

```
$datetime           = new \DateTime(''2021-03-23 11:20:15.000000'');
$datetimeZone       = $datetime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$datetimeZoneFormat = ucwords(strftime('%B %e, %Y', $datetimeZone->getTimestamp()));
```

Instead of the format function I had to use the strftime function and pass timestamp to achieve the result I wanted