# how to write a funtion to get each regions date by calling it in it's own language?

Tags: php, wordpress, calendar, hijri

I'm in wordpress and write some php to get Pesrian and Arabic date from Gregorian.
And I see this:
[Formatting DateTime object, respecting Locale::getDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744952/formatting-datetime-object-respecting-localegetdefault)

I want a function to get persian and arabic date each time function calls by simply change region and timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use languages other than English with the standard [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.date.php)/[`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/class.datetime.php) constructs in PHP. The only way to do this was to set the locale using [`setlocale()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.setlocale) and use the [`strfttime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.strftime.php) function... however that function is now deprecated in favor of using the [INTL/ICU](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension's [`IntlDateFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/class.intldateformatter.php) class:

```php
function getFormattedDateIntl(
    ?\DateTime $date = null,
    ?string $locale = null,
    ?DateTimeZone $timezone = null,
    string $dateFormat
) {
    $date = $date ?? new \DateTime();
    $locale = $locale ?? \Locale::getDefault();
    $formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(
        $locale,
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        $timezone,
        IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL,
        $dateFormat
    );
    return $formatter->format($date);
}

function getWeekdayIntl(
    ?\DateTime $date = null,
    ?string $locale = null,
    ?DateTimeZone $timezone = null
) {
    return getFormattedDateIntl($date, $locale, $timezone, 'eeee');
}

$islamicDateRight = getFormattedDateIntl(
    new DateTime(),
    'ar@calendar=islamic-civil',
    new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tehran'),
    'eeee dd MMMM'
);
```

Comment: A comprehensive answer, but please search for duplicate pages before wasting your time.  [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Comment: @Jim thanks, that works fine. My weekday purpose is arabic. Now can you tell how to return arabic month and day of month in your code?
MMMM return April in arabic ابریل  it should return رمضان.
and d returns 18 it should return 28.
Editing your code above for adding arabic month and day is highly appreciated

Comment: Also another problem is I want arabic or islamic date but my location is Tehran.
your code above makes one day delay in gregorian. for example the gregorian date of my time now is 2023-04-19 and in islamic (arabic) date is 1444-09-28. your code above returns 18 in gregorian

Comment: @Alipvd I updated the answer which should satisfy your request. Changing the format to `MMMM` should give Ramadan instead of April. The date being 1 date off is likely due to the timezone. Not sure why your server is using a different one, but this includes the ability to pass a timezone in and I added the Tehran timezone into the example.

Comment: @Jim thanks again. I edited some of your codes above to make more correct on my time zone "ar@calendar=islamic-civil" works great. also I added new parameter $dateFormat to your function because I want to use four times this function and it needs more to be dynamic.

Comment: @Alipvd - Thanks, I split it into 2 separate functions since they handle output differently and added formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convert_day_to_arabic($day) {
    $days = array(
        "Saturday" => "السبت",
        "Sunday" => "الأحد",
        "Monday" => "الإثنين",
        "Tuesday" => "الثلاثاء",
        "Wednesday" => "الأربعاء",
        "Thursday" => "الخميس",
        "Friday" => "الجمعة"
    );

    echo isset($days[$day]) ? $days[$day] : $day;
}
```

Comment: not workin. work on my code!

Comment: Where is the `match()` function call?