# How to output PHP gmdate for different languages

Tags: php, datetime

When using PHP's [gmdate() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) you can use a date format, this could be any combination of format from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

However, if the website has different language options a user can select from how can I ensure that the formatted date output from `gmdate()` is in the language selected?

```
echo gmdate( 'jS F Y', strtotime( '2023-05-01' ) ); // Outputs 30th April 2023
```

How can I get this to output as **30 avril 2023** if user is in France?

The language selected sets a variable like `fr_FR` which I am hoping I can use that in combination with `gmdate()` somehow to ensure the correct language date is output.

If `gmdate()` cannot be used for this scenario is there another function which offers similar formatting of a timestamp that is language aware (without having the intl extension)?

Comment: `gmdate` is almost identical to `date` but outputs the Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). Both of which aren't locale-aware. Do you have the `intl` extension enabled? If you do, you can use `IntlDateFormatter`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73250691/296555.

Comment: @waterloomatt I've just checked and no

Comment: Also, if you have `intl` installed _and_ you want to be prescriptive such as "I want to show the year as four digits, the days as two, and the month written out in full but in the person's locale", there's also the more complicated skeleton system: https://3v4l.org/ZQVO7#v8.2.5

Comment: @ChrisHaas unfortunately I do not have intl installed or available in this scenario. Is that the only option available to do this?

Comment: I don't have time to work up a demo, but you can use `setlocale` to switch over to another language (pass `0` the first time to get the current one back so that you can reset it when done) and then I think `gmstrftime` should use the locale. Note that that function is deprecated in PHP 8.1 in favor of `intl`