# Changing locale date language in PHP

Tags: php

I cannot seem to change the language of a date to Finnish. I installed the finnish language pack in my Linux install, restarted Nginx, and am using the following code :

```
<li><center>
?>Mitätöidä Myöhemmin <?echo date('l jS \of F Y');?></center></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Because PHP obeys you. It does what you tell it to, not what you have in mind. You need to specifically tell PHP to display the date in a particular locale. Use [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/setlocale) for that. See [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1328060/).

Comment: From the manual: *To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and strftime() functions instead of date().*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date()` will always output dates in the English language. If you wish to output them to a specific language, you'll need to use [`strftime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and pass in the necessary format.

You'll also need to tell PHP which language it should use with [`setlocale()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fi_FI');
echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y");
```