# Mysql and php database separation by MONTH

Tags: php, mysql

i am having a problem with php and mysql. i have database in which is column Date(Y-M-D) Date is actual date field no varchar
And what i want is to change that "number" to name of that current month. For example:

**2014-07-06**

- 2014-07-06 / 8:00 / Need for speed 3D / Kino

**2014-07-05**

- 2014-07-05 / 8:00 / Need for speed / Kino

**2014-06-06**

- 2014-07-06 / 8:00 / The Movie / Kino

ineed change that bold date to MONTH name (what i am expecting) :

**July**

- 2014-07-06 / 8:00 / Need for speed 3D / Kino
- 2014-07-05 / 8:00 / Need for speed / Kino

**June**

- 2014-07-06 / 8:00 / movie / Kino
- 2014-07-05 / 8:00 / second movie / Kino

My code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT hlavni.datum_expirace, hlavni.priloha, hlavni.nazev,
vedle.misto
FROM hlavni
INNER JOIN vedle ON hlavni.sekce = vedle.idecko WHERE vedle.idecko IN ( 6, 7, 8, 15, 14,
16, 17 ) ORDER BY `hlavni`.`datum_expirace` DESC, `hlavni`.`priloha` ASC");
//fetch tha data from the database 
$currentDate = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if ($row['datum_expirace'] != $currentDate){
echo
'<strong>' .  
$row['datum_expirace'] . 
'</strong>' ;
$currentDate = $row['datum_expirace'];
}
echo 
'<ul><li>' . 
$row['datum_expirace'] .
'</li><li>' .     
$row['priloha'] . 
'</li><li>' . 
$row['nazev'] .
'</li><li>' .     
$row['misto'] . 
'</li></ul>'; 
}
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions , they are deprecated and unsafe ! move over to mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo date('F', strtotime($row['datum_expirace']));
```

strtotime converts from the string to a date/time.

date('F') shows the date as the month name.

Written to be more in-line with your actual code example :

```
$cMonth = date('F', strtotime($row['datum_expirace']));

if ($cMonth != $currentDate)
{
    echo '<strong>' .  $cMonth  . '</strong>' ;
    $currentDate = $cMonth;
}
```

**Update**

Based on the comments, this might be better.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR'); //CALLED ONCE - with whatever language you need.
```

then

```
$cMonth = strftime('%B', strtotime($row['datum_expirace']));
```

**See also :**

[PHP Date function output in Italian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114488/php-date-function-output-in-italian)

[PHP date() in foreign languages - e.g. Mar 25 Aoû 09](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328036/php-date-in-foreign-languages-e-g-mar-25-aou-09)

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to accept the answer if it takes care of the problem =)

Comment: oh i will :D but right now i must wait 3 mins for accepting your answer

Comment: All this time here, and I didn't know there was a wait for approving answers. Anyhow, like I said, happy to help. Good luck with the rest of your project! =)

Comment: Can i have one more question ? i cant find how to set lc_time_names :(
Do you know how this work ? or is there a way to rename a Name of the month ?

Comment: I think this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328036/php-date-in-foreign-languages-e-g-mar-25-aou-09 -- Will update the answer.

Comment: i already did that :D but anyway... thank you ^^
Now i have problem with coding >.< when i change coding the MONTH name will be right BUT the rest of the text is messed up ... and when i revert changes then MONTH name is messed up and everything else is right xD

Comment: Check the first link (about Italian) the accepted answer shows how to switch to Italian and right back -- so that setting the local doesn't affect other functions. Maybe that would help?

Comment: well when i set:  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
the MONTHS names are messed up 
BUT
when header is not set: MONTHS are perfect but the rest of the text is messed up

Comment: I don't really have to work much with localization/character sets -- so I don't know the answer off the top of my head, sorry. Might be worth posting a new question if you can't find the answer.