# How to change language of formatted datetime in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and to format a datetime there was used format() method but the formatted datetime is displayed in English which I would like to change to German. How Is it possible to achieve. The code in view:`<small>Added {{$personal->created_at->format('F jS, Y')}}</small>`

Comment: Looks like similar problem there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328036/php-date-in-foreign-languages-e-g-mar-25-ao%C3%BB-09

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'German');
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');          // Mittwoch 21 Mai 1975
setlocale(LC_TIME, '');
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');          // Wednesday 21 May 1975
```