# Retrieving Day Names in PHP

Tags: php, date, locale

I need to display to user a list of localized day names (like 'Monday', 'Tuesday', ...) in a form. I know ho to get day name of any date. But is there a particular and fail-proof way to get all day names in an array.

Edit: I could add names of days to my translation file but that is hard to maintain.

Comment: Day names? Do you mean like `Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday... etc?`

Comment: Why not define them yourself? It's usually the best way to go because asking `date()` depends on locale settings that are notoriously unreliable.

Comment: *(reference)* http://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.format.php

Comment: *(reference)* http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: Any localization solution needs to be considered within your overall localization strategy. Vascowhite's solution is not necessarily locale specific but it viable as the basis for a number of different localization solutions.  See my comment, and note his adjustment.  If you use the numeric index for the date, that will allow you to get a predictable string which you can then use as the key to return the localized string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3729069/1481489 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729038/how-do-i-get-locale-day-and-month#comment30318102_3729069

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) in combination with [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) is an option.

However you should be aware that on threaded php installs, `setlocale()` can behave unexpected, since locale information is maintained per process, not per thread. Therefor it is important to call `setlocale()` every time before each call to `strftime()` to guarantee it uses the correct locale.

Also, for Windows systems, you need to use somewhat unusual strings for the `$locale` parameter for `setlocale()`.

See the docs for more information on both of these issues.

Something like this should work:

```
// define the locales for setlocale() for which we need the daynames
$locales = array(
  'en_EN',
  'de_DE',
  'nl_NL'
  // etc...
);

// be aware that setlocale() needs different values on Windows machines
// see the docs on setlocale() for more information
$locales = array(
  'english',
  'german',
  'dutch'
  // etc...
);

// let's remember the current local setting
$oldLocale = setlocale( LC_TIME, '0' );

// initialize out result array
$localizedWeekdays = array();

// loop each locale
foreach( $locales as $locale )
{
    // create sub result array for this locale 
    $localizedWeekdays[ $locale ] = array();

    // 7 days in a week
    for( $i = 0; $i < 7; $i++ )
    {
        // set the locale on each iteration again
        setlocale( LC_TIME, $locale );

        // combine strftime() with the nifty strtotime()
        $localizedWeekdays[ $locale ][] = strftime( '%A', strtotime( 'next Monday +' . $i . ' days' ) );

        // reset the locale for other threads, as a courtesy
        setlocale( LC_TIME, $oldLocale );
    }
}

// there is your result in a multi-dimensional array
var_dump( $localizedWeekdays );
```

Comment: Please note, that localized weekdays are returned in `windows-1250` rather than `utf-8`. Additional encoding conversion e.g. via `iconv` may be needed. Tested on Win64 PHP 7.0.

Answer (score 33):

```
$date = '2011/10/14'; 
$day = date('l', strtotime($date));
echo $day;
```

Comment: It's suddenly not working after working and I stopped apache! It is now return the number instead of the day name...

Comment: Thanks for saving my day.

Answer (score 5):

The "usual" way is to start with a given `last day` and count up a day on each iteration.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
  $weekDayNames[] = strftime("%a", strtotime("last sunday +$i day"));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$dayNames = array(
    'Sunday',
    'Monday', 
    'Tuesday', 
    'Wednesday', 
    'Thursday', 
    'Friday', 
    'Saturday', 
 );
```

Is pretty fail-proof :)

On a more serious note, the likes of PHPBB do this by defining localization files and hard coding for different languages. It's really the only way to do this reliably.

I would recommend downloading something like that and looking at the code to see how its done.

http://www.phpbb.com/downloads/olympus.php

Comment: It's hard to maintain for all languages and that makes me a sad panda.

Comment: If you are going to do this, it should be 'Sunday', ... 'Saturday' to coincide with the return from date('w') where Sunday is the 0th element.

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');

$today = ( 86400 * (date("N")) );

for( $i = 0; $i < 7; $i++ ) {
    $days[] = strftime('%A', time() - $today + ($i*86400));
}

print_r($days);
```

Obviously can be optimised by not calling time() 7 times etc but that's the gist. It gives you the right language for the locale and keeps Sun-Sat order of the array in tact.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a long time, but what about:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('next Sunday');
$days = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
 $days[] = strftime('%A', $timestamp);
 $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
}
```

from [how to create array of a week days name in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536748/how-to-create-array-of-a-week-days-name-in-php)

Comment: I don't see any difference between this solution and approved solution.

Answer (score -2):

This code will work pretty well:-

```
$dayNames = array(
    0=>'Sunday',
    1=>'Monday', 
    2=>'Tuesday', 
    3=>'Wednesday', 
    4=>'Thursday', 
    5=>'Friday', 
    6=>'Saturday', 
 );
```

Now for example you wants to get the any day from array:-

```
echo $dayNames[1]; //Output:- Monday
```