# need help in sql database to retrieve day from date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm fetching data from the sql database

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE id='$id'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

    $title = $row["title"];
    $contents = $row["contents"];
    $author = $row["author"];
    $date = $row["date"];
     $date = strftime("%b %d, %y", strtotime($date));   

     }
```

and then I use print $date to view the date.
How can also get the day from that date..like sunday, monday ?

Comment: Since you tagged it with `sql`, you should read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Comment: It doesn't answer my ques. It's for preventing sql injection and the code I provided in the question is just an example to describe my problem.

Comment: You should also take note [of this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#comment19286459_60174).

Comment: Thing is, I'm not a php programmer, but I am an sql programmer, so I thought I'd still try to help.

Comment: are you storing date using DateTime data type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving Day Names in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765469/retrieving-day-names-in-php)

Comment: If you store the DATETIME format in database, you could use sql query to get day of the week and dont have to convert them using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `$day = date('l', strtotime($date));`

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765469/retrieving-day-names-in-php).

In summary: `$day = date('l', strtotime($date));`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the query to return day of week instead of using PHP, You could use DATE_FORMAT function that is built into the database like this.

```
 select *, DATE_FORMAT(entryDate, '%W') as dayOfWeek from entries
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the MySQL function DAYOFWEEK:

```
SELECT *, DAYOFWEEK(`date`) AS day FROM entries WHERE id='$id'
```

And a full PHP example with your code (even though my strong opinion is that you should switch to using [PDO or MYSQLI driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php))

```
$days = array(
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
);


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *, DAYOFWEEK(`date`) AS day FROM entries WHERE id='$id'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

    $title = $row["title"];
    $contents = $row["contents"];
    $author = $row["author"];
    $date = $row["date"];
    $date = strftime("%b %d, %y", strtotime($date));   
    $day = $days[$row["day"]-1];
     }
```