# Display which day it is? sunday or monday "php coding"?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, timestamp

$date = date('Y-m-d h:i');

I have been using this function for recording date in my tables. Previosuly i use to create date using wrong function like mktime.

Comment: This is not how you ask questions. Don't assume that an image of a web page makes our crystal ball fire up and enlighten us on what your code is.

Comment: what kind of info you need,bcoz i am learning it and unable to understand it how should i convert my this date into displaying which day it was. This image is for understanding... so here you can understand...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving Day Names in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765469/retrieving-day-names-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy one:

```
$today = date('l'); // returns Sunday
```

When you want it to do like your image, you should get your date from the dropdown. Then do the following:

```
$date = '2017-7-27 10:51:10'; // example date 

var_dump(date('l', strtotime($date))); // returns Sunday
```

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks for understanding it.. I have done some similar to it. please check it out... thanks...

Comment: Sure, But I have to use $years $Months $days variable to get days... I have used your example and it display correctly...