# Translating date to default language or selected language

Tags: php

I have to display a date that I pick from my DB, the date is always displayed in english, my site is bilangue, EN/DE.

my PHP code

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.utf8");
    ...
    $myDate='2016-06-17'; //example
    echo strftime(date_format(date_create($myDate), "l, j  F Y "))
```

But this doesn't work, I get it always in EN `Friday, 17 June 2016`

UPDATE : I could use

```
strftime("%B %e, %G",date_timestamp_get(date_create($myDate)))
```

I get `Juni 17, 2016` ,but then I lose the name of the day so I have to use also `date_format`

Comment: Possible duplication: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716427/output-php-date-with-the-right-language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716427/output-php-date-with-the-right-language)

Comment: it is not a duplication, I don't use date() function

Comment: What is the result of `setlocale`? (try `var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.utf8"))`)

Comment: string 'de_DE.utf8' (length=10)

Comment: OK, so the locale used exists on your system. The problem is elsewhere then.

Comment: @AlissonLinneker The OP here is already using `setlocale` and `strftime` as suggested in the answer of the question you linked to.

Comment: @smile22121 On new code, use: `strftime("%A, %e %B %G",date_timestamp_get(date_create($myDate)));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code gives the expected result:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.utf8");
$myDate='2016-06-17'; //example
echo strftime("%A, %e %B %Y", date_create($myDate)->getTimestamp());
```

According to the documentation, [strftime](http://php.net/strftime) arguments are a format string and a timestamp. The second argument you provided is not a timestamp.

Comment: You are my hero, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There're mainly two problems:

- Don't stick to one proper date data type and mix it with too many strings.
- Don't use functions as the documentation explains.

The [strftime()](http://php.net/strftime) function expects a Unix timestamp as second argument but [date_format()](http://php.net/date_format) returns a string (it *could* return a string with a timestamp but it doesn't because of `l, j  F Y`). You are also using [strftime()](http://php.net/strftime) wrong: the first argument is the format, not the timestamp. Additionally, you are using `DateTime` objects as proxy without any benefit.

Try something simpler:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.utf8");
$myDate = strtotime('2016-06-17'); //example
echo strftime('Write proper format there', $myDate);
```