# PHP: convert timestamp to local time, then display in local language

Tags: php, timezone, multilingual, strftime, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a timestamp in a mysql database. I want to convert it from the server time to the local time, then display it in the local language.

This works to convert the time zone and display in English:
(I have functions which select the local time zone and language. But below I just post the code as if the time-zone and language fields are hard-coded.)

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$my_time = $row['timestamp'];
$my_time = new DateTime($my_time);
$my_time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
echo $my_time->format("F Y");
```

It correctly displays "August, 2013", for example.

But I can't get it to convert the time zone and then display in local language. I tried different ways. Sometimes I get unix time, some ways I get short dates. I'm tied up in knots trying to solve this.

The best I got was this (which I found in a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114488/php-date-function-output-in-italian) on this site):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$my_time = $row['timestamp'];
$oldLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT');
echo strftime("%F %Y", $my_time);
setlocale(LC_TIME, $oldLocale);
```

But no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: DateTime objects don't support languages other than English for formatting: use `$timestamp = $my_time->format('U');`, and then feed that value to strftime(), having set the appropriate locale

Comment: Thanks. I tried converting the zone of $my_time with setTimezone, then put in Unix time [format('U')], set locale with setlocale, then strftime. It works to get the time in local language. But it loses the timezone conversion, and just gives the server time back. How to convert the time zone AND output in non-English language?