# Why wont php show local weekday

Tags: php, date

Why cant I get the weekdays in danish (mandag, tirsdag...) when I get the date from MySQL?

`$Weekday = date('l', strtotime($Date));`

`echo " - $Weekday";`

I have tryed to set locale settings, but it dosn't work? It only returns in english.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Date function output in Italian](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114488/php-date-function-output-in-italian)

Answer (score 0):

The locale does not affect `date()` function, you should use `strftime()` and set the locale like this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'Portuguese');
echo strftime('%A');
```

Other options are:

[gmstrftim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmstrftime.php)

[Carbon lib](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)

[IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php)