# How to show a DateTime in the format '23 February 2018'

Tags: php, date, datetime

I've a string like this: 2018-02-21 15:10:23.
I need to show a date like this '23 Febbraio 2018' and, I used this code to convert the string to a DateTime:

```
$post_date_to_DateTime = new DateTime($post_date_string);
$post_date = $post_date_to_DateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Now, I have to extract Month in format Text and day and year in number to compose the date (in Italian).
There's a fast method using some php date functions or I have to create an array with all Months Italian names and then create a specific string?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `format('d F Y');` Take a look here about the format options: http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This (Your Requirement):

```
$post_date = date('j F Y', strtotime('2018-02-21 15:10:23'));
```

For More Formatting Please check PHP - date 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT');
echo (strftime("%e %B %Y", strtotime("02/28/2002")) );

/*OUTPUT*/
28 febbraio 2002
```

Read before this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1114547/5803974

Answer (score 0):

according to https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
you can get the english month name with:

```
$post_date_to_DateTime->format('F');
```

to get italian names you will have to define them by your self, like you already guessed.

Answer (score 0):

use `strftime` — Format a local time/date according to locale settings

```
echo strftime('%e %B %Y', strtotime('2018-02-21 15:10:23'));
```

`%d`    Two-digit day of the month (with leading zeros)     01 to 31

`%e`    Day of the month, with a space preceding single digits. 1 to 31

`%B`    Full month name, based on the locale    January through December

`%Y`    Four digit representation for the year  Example: 2038

For more info [Click Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)